# Ошибка создания базы данных в postgresql

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql, asyncpg

Пытаюсь создать и взаимодействовать с базой данных PostgreSQL, используя Python и asyncpg. При запуске программы постоянно появляются следующие ошибки:

```
**ConnectionResetError: [WinError 64] Указанное сетевое имя более недоступно**
```

и ещё:

```
**asyncpg.exceptions.ConnectionDoesNotExistError: connection was closed in the middle of operation**
```

Может кто-то знает, из-за чего могут возникать подобные ошибки?

```py
from typing import Union
import asyncpg
from asyncpg import Connection
from asyncpg.pool import Pool
from data import config

class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pool: Union[Pool, None] = None

    async def create(self):
        self.pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(
            user=config.DB_USER,
            password=config.DB_PASS,
            host=config.DB_HOST,
            database=config.DB_NAME,
            max_inactive_connection_lifetime=3
        )

    async def execute(self, command, *args,
                      fetch: bool = False,
                      fetchval: bool = False,
                      fetchrow: bool = False,
                      execute: bool = False
                      ):
        async with self.pool.acquire() as connection:
            connection: Connection
            async with connection.transaction():
                if fetch:
                    result = await connection.fetch(command, *args)
                elif fetchval:
                    result = await connection.fetchval(command, *args)
                elif fetchrow:
                    result = await connection.fetchrow(command, *args)
                elif execute:
                    result = await connection.execute(command, *args)
            return result

    async def create_table_users(self):
        sql = """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        full_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        username varchar(255) NULL,
        telegram_id BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE
        );
        """
        await self.execute(sql, execute=True)

    @staticmethod
    def format_args(sql, parameters: dict):
        sql += " AND ".join([
            f"{item} = ${num}" for num, item in enumerate(parameters.keys(),
                                                          start=1)
        ])
        return sql, tuple(parameters.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка создания базы данных в postgresql может быть вызвана различными причинами. Некоторые из наиболее распространенных причин такой ошибки могут быть следующими:

1. Неверно указаны данные для подключения к базе данных. Убедитесь, что вы правильно указали имя пользователя, пароль, хост и имя базы данных в конфигурационном файле `config.py`.
2. Порт для подключения к базе данных заблокирован фаерволом. Убедитесь, что порт, который используется для подключения к базе данных, разрешен в фаерволе.
3. Не установлен клиент PostgreSQL. Убедитесь, что у вас установлен клиент PostgreSQL и настроен путь к нему в системной переменной `PATH`.
4. Не установлен модуль `asyncpg`. Убедитесь, что вы установили модуль `asyncpg` с помощью команды `pip install asyncpg`.